# arrange side by side div

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to have following layout of div

[image]

How can i achieve this? I tried below code

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class=" col-md-4 " style="">
        <div class="relative">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.imagesfestival.com/images/resize.php?width=350&src=images/news/216.jpg" />
            <div class="tip">
                 <h3><a href="#" title="Elgen i baksetet">Test block1</a></h3>
                <div class="text"> <em><a href="#">AAAA</a></em>    
                    <p>Test paragraph 1</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class=" col-md-4 " style="">
        <div class="relative">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.imagesfestival.com/images/resize.php?width=350&src=images/news/216.jpg" />
            <div class="tip">
                 <h3><a href="#" title="Leasing – Et trekantforhold">Test block 2</a></h3>
                <div class="text"> <em><a href="#">BBBB</a></em>    
                    <p>New paragraph</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="  col-md-4 " style="">
        <div class="relative">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.imagesfestival.com/images/resize.php?width=350&src=images/news/216.jpg" />
            <div class="tip">
                 <h3><a href="#" title="Leasingforløpet">New title</a></h3>
                <div class="text"> <em><a href="http://minleasing.no/category/leasing/">Title block 3</a></em>  
                    <p>Paragraph</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class=" col-md-4 " style="">
        <div class="relative">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.imagesfestival.com/images/resize.php?width=350&src=images/news/216.jpg" />
            <div class="tip">
                 <h3><a href="#" title="Elgen i baksetet">Title3</a></h3>
                <div class="text"> <em><a href="#">Title block 4</a></em>

                    <p>Paragrpah start</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class=" col-md-4 " style="">
        <div class="relative">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.imagesfestival.com/images/resize.php?width=350&src=images/news/216.jpg" />
            <div class="tip">
                 <h3><a href="#" title="Leasing – Et trekantforhold">FFFFFFFFFFF</a></h3>
                <div class="text"> <em><a href="#">GGGGGGGGG</a></em>

                    <p>GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="  col-md-4 " style="">
        <div class="relative">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.imagesfestival.com/images/resize.php?width=350&src=images/news/216.jpg" />
            <div class="tip">
                 <h3><a href="#" title="Leasingforløpet">Gdddfdf</a></h3>
                <div class="text"> <em><a href="http://minleasing.no/category/leasing/">aaagr</a></em>

                    <p>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="sidediv" class="row" style="float:left">
     This is my side DIV
</div>
```

But it comes down and not on side. I have defined div called `sidediv` which i want on side. Remember that it should be responsive hence want to use bootstrap.

here is [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pk1pr96n/104/)

Comment: Could you provide the css and/or create a JSFiddle for this scenario please?

Comment: @DanielCasserly Please check question. I added fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wrap it all in one more `row` and arrange side by side with `col-md-`

Like this

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class=" col-md-8 " >
         -YOUR SMALL BLOCK ROWS
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">This is my side DIV</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is an example [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pk1pr96n/105/)

#### Note: Arranges side by side only on big sized screens because `col-md` is used. If you want it to be arranged side by side on small screens use `col-sm` or `col-xs` accordingly.

## UPD1:

refering to our dialog in comments the updated css part

### css

```
.tip {
    background: #eee;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    height:150px;
}
.tip .text p
{
    overflow:hidden;
    max-height:60px;

}
```

And an updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pk1pr96n/107/)

Comment: Is it possible to have fixed height of div. Currently if text below image is more or less then they dont appear of same size

Comment: Refer this website http://minleasing.no/ for example. I want to have div arranged in same manner

Comment: @Happy it is possible to do this with `display:flex`  but it will interfere with bootstraps `float` settings. Also the site you provided has set `max-height` and `min-height` to the tip div to achieve this and they're having problems with this on the last row where text overflows the tip div.

Comment: @Happy you can add an `overflow:hidden` to your `<p>` inside the `tip` and set the `max-height` of it fixed. Then set `height` of the `tip` fixed.

Comment: can you quickly tell how?

Answer (score 0):

The image that you provided is replicated in the following fiddle. I made an assumption that since you haven't provided a size for your boxes, the smaller ones can be contained in xs-2 wrapper and the larger one occupies a xs-4 wrapper. However, you can alter it as per your requirements later on. Hope this helps :)

Fiddle link - 
    
https://jsfiddle.net/pk1pr96n/106/

Code for the HTML is basically

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4">
         <div class="col-xs-6">
             <img src="http://www.myitchydog.co.uk/user/small-dog-playing.jpg" width="100%">
         </div>
         <div class="col-xs-6">
             <img src="http://www.myitchydog.co.uk/user/small-dog-playing.jpg" width="100%">
         </div>
         <div class="col-xs-6">
             <img src="http://www.myitchydog.co.uk/user/small-dog-playing.jpg" width="100%">
         </div>
         <div class="col-xs-6">
             <img src="http://www.myitchydog.co.uk/user/small-dog-playing.jpg" width="100%">
         </div>
     </div>
   <div class="col-xs-4">
        <img src="http://payload47.cargocollective.com/1/2/66131/3250877/unicornmirror9x12etsy_860.jpg" width="100%">
   </div>
 </div>
```